# Version history to correct the Creation date for all earlier versions

Tags: 2013

How to edit the Policy Versions tab in ribbon in Sharepoint ?

I have migrated some data to Sharepoint with all the version history and documents .  But the created date is not right .

How can i correct the creation date for all the versions ? For auditing purpose i know sharepoint doesnt provide a code to update previous history .

To add i have managed to get the correct data into a seperate sharepoint list .

Comment: It sounds to me the software you used to migrate the content didn't work correctly. If it did, the dates would be correct.

Comment: yes you are right .

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear that. There really isn't a good fix other than a successful re migration.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant do a remigration :(

Comment: Hi Nikhil, do you have access to the source data? You can update the previous version information, but that intern may create a new version. If you have access to the previous info, you can use PowerShell to update content, you can try using $item.SystemUpdate($false) if you used CSOM try using // Checkin the file with Overwrite to maintain the version
        file.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);